DVTPlugInQuery: Requested but did not find extension point with identifier 'Xcode.InterfaceBuilderBuildSupport.PlatformDefinition'

DVTPlugInQuery: Requested but did not find extension point with identifier 'Xcode.InterfaceBuilderBuildSupport.PlatformDefinition'. This is programmer error; code should only request extension points that are defined by itself or its dependencies.

I am getting this warning while building a react native application. How do I resolve this?

This message may help you, I was facing the same issue: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/2383#issuecomment-2440664971

It seems like if I don't touch an RN project for a couple of weeks, I get an error like this. I had this exact same issue. I tried a couple of related question/answers with no luck (Can't build react-native app due to errant recursive path issue) and (PBXCp error ..... is longer than filepath buffer size (1025)), but I don't believe these are related to our problem. I fixed this particular issue the same way I've been fixing a lot of XCode issues:
Assuming you are on Mac OS X:

Close XCode and the Simulator.
Go to Activity Monitor and force quit any "simulator" tasks. I had two different ones running.
Open Settings->Storage Settings, then select "Developer", then delete "Xcode Caches"

After this, try again -- the application should build and the simulator should open successfully.

Didn't resolve the issue for me. Thanks for posting, anyway.

The accepted answer by @jbnunn didn't work for me unfortunately. Ended up being an xcode update for the iOS version I had installed. Fixed by installing the new version. In xcode:

Open settings => "Platforms" tab.
If you have an uninstalled iOS version available click on the "GET" button on the right side to install.

Once the installation is finished you should have a new set of simulators available with the iOS version you just installed and the build should be successful.

I did this and the steps from accepted response. I still get the same message.
